# Predicting values using TFLearn neural networks

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, tflearn

I am new to TFLearn and I am trying out a simple neural network to predict the output array value when an input array is given.

Actual input for this code would be either pixel values of a grayscale image or features extracted from a grayscale image. Hence the input is in a 2d array format. The output would be the predicted color for each pixel.

In the example code I have used two random arrays of size 9. I need to train the network to predict the 't_y' array when 't_x' array is given as input.
The code runs, but the prediction is very poor.

The code has been adapted from MNIST example of TFLearn found [here](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/convnet_mnist.py)

This is my code

```
from random import randint
import numpy as np
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.normalization import local_response_normalization
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression



#input
t_x = [3, 8, 7, 4, 0, 7, 9, 5, 1]
#output
t_y = [9, 5, 1, 4, 7, 9, 7, 3, 6]

x = []
y = []

for i in range(1000):
  x.append(t_x)
  y.append(t_y)

#array of input values
x = np.reshape(x,(-1,3,3,1))

#array of output values
y = np.reshape(y,(-1,9))

network = input_data(shape=[None, 3, 3, 1], name='input')
network = conv_2d(network, 32, 3, activation='relu', regularizer="L2")
network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)
network = local_response_normalization(network)
network = conv_2d(network, 64, 3, activation='relu', regularizer="L2")
network = max_pool_2d(network, 2)
network = local_response_normalization(network)
network = fully_connected(network, 128, activation='tanh')
network = dropout(network, 0.8)
network = fully_connected(network, 256, activation='tanh')
network = dropout(network, 0.8)
network = fully_connected(network, 9, activation='softmax')
network = regression(network, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=0.01,
                     loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='target')


# Training
model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_verbose=0)
model.fit({'input': x}, {'target': y}, n_epoch=20)

pred = model.predict(np.reshape(t_x,(-1,3,3,1)))
print "Prediction :", pred[0]
```

I am assuming it has something to do with the parameter values specified in the 'conv_2d' and 'fully_connnected' functions.

What values would I have to set to get an accurate prediction ?

Answer (score 1):

### Format of output

The last layer of your code (fully_connected(network, 9, activation='softmax')) results in 9 neurons with a softmax function, i.e. normalised so that their total sum will add up to 1. This is generally usable (and used in MNIST) for selecting/optimizing a function that selects one of 9 possible output values - the network will output something like [0.01 0.01 0.01 0.9 0.03 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01], "predicting" that the fourth value is the correct one, and this would be matched against a one-hot target vector (e.g. [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]).

Needless to say, a softmax output cannot ever be equal to [9, 5, 1, 4, 7, 9, 7, 3, 6], and not even close to that, since the output of all values softmax will add up to 1. Even the layer before that cannot output such values since tanh can only produce values between -1 and 1, and can't ever result in 9.

If you want to predict 9 numbers in the range 1-9, then you might want to use a fully connected layer instead of softmax, and scale your output so that the expected output is in the range of 0 to 1. There's more to that, but this would be a good start.

Comment: Is there a way to limit the output values of network layer to a range of values, say 0 - 9 ?

Comment: @AkheelKM have a standard 0-1 activation function and multiply it by 9; it's an often used machine learning practice to scale (or log-scale) all variables to something like 0-1 and re-scale them back on output.